# How to find vector of items in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, find, std

if there is vector and we need to find more than one item with the same condition.
if we called `std::find_if` it will return the first appearance of the  condition.

```
 std::vector <int> List{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    auto item = find_if(List.begin(), List.end(), [](int x)
    {
        return x > 2;
    }
    );
```

I know we can use `std::for_each` and put the condition and the action inside the lambda expression, but I am asking if there is a method which do it itself and return a vector of found items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to populate a vector with copies of the items satisfying the predicate.

```
#include <vector>     // vector
#include <iterator>   // copy_if
#include <algorithm>  // back_inserter

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> List{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
  std::vector<int> good_items;

  std::copy_if(List.begin(), List.end(), std::back_inserter(good_items),
             [](int x) { return x > 2; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) together with `std::back_inserter` should do the trick